# How to VueJS redirect /blog to GhostJS on subdirectory?

Tags: nginx, vuejs2, vue-router, ghost-blog, nuxt.js

**STATUS: SOLVED!**

Before you start typing, here is my scenario:

My VueJS website is actually a NuxtJS website (dockerized).
I also dockerized GhostJS to act as my blog module container to run on 192.168.99.100/blog (hopefully).
I also have a 3rd container which is jwilder's nginx-proxy to act as my reverse proxy (and will also serve HTTPS once I deploy the site to public). I have this to do /blog for ghost (as well as having the proper config.production.json settings for subdirectory).

**The Problem**
When I access 192.168.99.100, it takes me to my Nuxt.js (perfect!).
HOWEVER, once I do 192.168.99.100/blog, the Nuxt framework interferes which stops me from accessing my GhostJS blog. What can I do in order to prevent this interference from happening? All I want is once the user does /blog, GhostJS kicks in. :'(

Thanks.

***SOLUTION***
I figured out how to fix it. Used a regular nGinx container (instead of jwilder's). Used 192.168.99.100 as the proxy pass path with respective exposed ports. Removed  for /blog (which is the main reason why the framework kept overriding my /blog request). Everything worked perfectly - almost. Just have to figure out how to not expose the two ports to the outside world and only in localhost level... hmmm. and LetsEncrypt into a nginx container.... hmmm

Comment: try to adjust your nginx configuration file.

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev The issue is that the nuxt.js framework is overriding the route request to /blog but i will check the config file too :)

Comment: Your proxy can look for */blog inside url and then redirect to your blog.

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev So I've been playing around with the conf file more and sadly no luck. The Nuxt.js framework keeps kicking in and saying /blog is not a valid route.

Comment: @papey I've been trying to do that, but no luck. Nuxt keeps on overriding the nginx proxy

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev So I played with it more, and got it to work sort of (insecurely). The problem left now is the two ports are exposed, but it is also the only way for nginx container to find the thing without Nuxt.js (aka vue.js) to override nginx :(. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION I figured out how to fix it. Used a regular nGinx container (instead of jwilder's). Used 192.168.99.100 as the proxy pass path with respective exposed ports. Removed for /blog (which is the main reason why the framework kept overriding my /blog request). Everything worked perfectly - almost. Just have to figure out how to not expose the two ports to the outside world and only in localhost level... hmmm. and LetsEncrypt into a nginx container.... hmmm